# Bijective Proofs: The number of subsets of $\left[n\right] = \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ equals the number of $n$-digit binary numbers.

Tags: combinatorics

Give a bijective proof of the following: The number of subsets of $\left[n\right] = \left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ equals the number of $n$-digit binary numbers.

I do not understand how to do this problem, can someone help me figure it out?

I have this so far,

Let *f* be the function that takes as its input a subset of [*n*] and outputs an *n*-digit binary number that has 1s in the positions that correspond to the elements of the subset.

I have to prove that *f* is a bijection now, and I am stuck on doing that.

Comment: I have seen this phrase before. What kind of class or book uses the phrase "bijective proof?"

Comment: Combinatorics is the name of the book. Class is called Discrete Mathematics.

Comment: Apparently it is a real phrase. How very strange. I don't see a need for it;   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a concrete value of $n$ to understand how the pieces fit together here.

How many $2$-digit binary numbers are there? 
$$
    00, 10, 01, 11
$$
How many subsets of $[2] = \{1,2\}$ are there?
$$\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\} $$

Notice that there's a natural correspondence here, let the first digit of the binary number mean "whether or not you include $1$ in the subset" ($1$ for include it, $0$ for omit it), the second digit is "whether or not you include $2$ in the subset".

Comment: OK, I understand this, I am just having some trouble putting it together using variables only.

Comment: Try writing out what you have so far as an edit in your original post, and we can give more specific help (otherwise it's hard to help without just *giving* you the solution, something we try and avoid here). Try replacing words like "first" and "second" in my sketch with "$k$-th"$.

Comment: I did the edit.

Comment: Ok, looks good so far. Now you just need to demonstrate $f$ is injective (1-1) and surjective (onto). Answer these questions in your own words: "if two subsets of $[n]$ are distinct, can they be mapped to the *same* binary number?" and "given an $n$-digit binary number, is there always a subset of $[n]$ that maps to this number?"

Comment: OK, thanks! I think I can take it from here!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a bijective relationship between elements in [n] being in or not in a subset, and digits in a binary number being 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

For example, take $n = 6$, and imagine the subset $X$ = {$2,3,4,6$} of {$1,2,3,4,5,6$}.

Associate to $X$ the string (No, Yes, Yes, Yes, No, Yes).

Replace Yes with bit $1$ and No with bit $0$.